# Getting count of strings using Binary Search Tree in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-3, binary-search-tree

I want to get the count of various strings stored in different files. Actually I need two types of counts. For a string str,

1.) Total no of occurrences of the string str throughout all the files.
2.) Number of files having the string str.

Below is my RUBY Code for it in which i have managed to get the total count.
But i can't get the file count. I have used arrays instead of files for simplicity(analogous to files) and an instance variable 'flag'.

My concept is that if flag = 0, it means the string is encountered for the first time in the first array. So the filecount(or arraycount in this case) is incremented and flag is set to 1. So when the same string appears in the same array , flag is already set to 1 and nothing happens.
**When an array is over, all the flag values are set back to 0.**(I think so)

But something's not working as expected. Thanks in Advance..!

```
    class Tree
  attr_accessor :left
  attr_accessor :right
  attr_accessor :data
  attr_accessor :count
  attr_accessor :flag
  attr_accessor :howmanyfiles

  def initialize(x=nil)
   @left = nil
   @right = nil
   @data = x
   @count = 1
   @flag = 0
   @howmanyfiles = 1
  end


  def search(x)
      if self.data == x
        self.count = self.count + 1
        if self.flag == 0
          self.howmanyfiles = self.howmanyfiles + 1
        end
       return "#{self.data} found" #self
      else
       ltree = left != nil ? left.search(x) : nil
       return ltree if ltree != nil
       rtree = right != nil ? right.search(x) : nil
       return rtree if rtree != nil
      end
    nil
  end


  def insert(x)
   list = []

   if @data == nil
    @data = x
    self.flag = 1
   elsif @left == nil
    @left = Tree.new(x)
    self.flag = 1
   elsif @right == nil
    @right = Tree.new(x)
    self.flag = 1
   else
    list << @left
    list << @right
    loop do
     node = list.shift
     if node.left == nil
      node.insert(x)
      break
     else
      list << node.left
     end
     if node.right == nil
      node.insert(x)
      break
     else
      list << node.right
     end
    end
   end



  end

  def traverse()
   list = []
   yield @data
   list << @left if @left != nil
   list << @right if @right != nil
   loop do
    break if list.empty?
    node = list.shift
    yield node.data
    list << node.left if node.left != nil
    list << node.right if node.right != nil
   end
  end






end


  items = ["Amal","Hai", "Bob", "Bob", "Cat", "Cat", "Amal", "Dog", "Rizu", "Zol","Amal"]

  tree = Tree.new

  items.each {|x|

    if tree.search(x) == nil
       tree.insert(x)
     end}


     ObjectSpace.each_object(Tree) do |obj|
      obj.flag = 0
     end

     items1 = ["Amal","wet", "jjj", "Cat"]
     items1.each {|x|

       if tree.search(x) == nil
          tree.insert(x)
        end}



        ObjectSpace.each_object(Tree) do |obj|
         obj.flag = 0
        end

        items2 = ["aa","Amal", "jjj"]
        items2.each {|x|

          if tree.search(x) == nil
             tree.insert(x)
           end}

     ObjectSpace.each_object(Tree) do |obj|
    puts obj.data.to_s + " " + obj.count.to_s + " " + obj.howmanyfiles.to_s
   end

  tree.traverse {|x|  print "#{x} "}
  print "\n"
```

OUTPUT - in format of string         total_count        ArrayCount

```
aa 1 1
jjj 2 2
wet 1 1
Zol 1 1
Rizu 1 1
Dog 1 1
Cat 3 2
Bob 2 2  <--Bob is only present in first array but still output says 2.
Hai 1 1
Amal 5 3
Amal Hai Bob Cat Dog Rizu Zol wet jjj aa
```

Comment: What is the error you are encountering? Could you share the stack trace or output of the program in contrast  to the expected output?

Comment: My count for the number of arrays having string Bob is wrong.
As you can see, only one array has Bob but output list count as 2.

Comment: Indentation here is a bit of a mess. Do try and keep your code as organized as possible when asking questions as clarity helps communicate intent.

Comment: You also **really** do not want to do this: `ObjectSpace.each_object(Tree)`.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems clear from the first two paragraphs, but I can't understand how a binary search tree could be used to advantage. My solution is a straigtforward approach to obtaining the desired counts.

**Code**

```
def get_counts(filenames, target)
  filenames.each_with_object([0, 0]) do |fname, arr|
    n = File.read(fname).scan(/#{target}/).size
    next if n.zero?
    arr[0] += n
    arr[1] += 1
  end
end
```

where `files` is an array of filenames and `target` is the string we are searching for.

**Example**

Let's start by making 3 test files.

```
filenames  = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
text       = ["Hoya, Bob. Your bro's name is Bob too. Eh?",
              "I gotta go feed my cat",
              "A girl named Bob?"]

filenames.zip(text).each { |fname, str| File.write(fname, str) }
```

Confirm the files were written:

```
filenames.map { |fname| File.read(fname) }
  #=> ["Hoya, Bob. Your bro's name is Bob too. Eh?", 
  #    "I gotta go feed my cat",
  #    "A girl named Bob?"]
```

Suppose we are looking for the string

```
target = 'Bob'
```

Then

```
tot, files = get_counts(filenames, target)
  #=> [3, 2] 
tot
  #=> 3 
files
  #=> 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Cary . But I have some doubts.
I need to carry out this search process for each and every line(string) present in around 1000+ files each having 20,00,000+ lines.

I tried to do a normal linear search but it takes a lot of time. So i was asked to use a binary search tree to cut short the time.

So, what algorithm does the  scan method in ruby use? or is there any efficient way in which i can get this thing done?

Comment: Not knowing you were dealing with large files, I gulped each file into a string using [IO#read](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-i-read). For files that big you would read the file line-by-line (using, say, [IO#for_each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach)). My code would change very little. You would apply [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-scan) to each line and sum those totals over all lines... (cont.)

Comment: ...My answer is for searching strings, not words or substrings of words (because that was not part of the question's spec). If you want words, you need to do things differently (e.g., use a regular expression with word boundaries). If, for example, you were searching for the word "cat", but just searched for that string, "catsup", "catch" and so on would be counted....(cont.)

Comment: ...If you are searching for a large number of individual words (not strings), it might make sense to extract all words from a file into an array, sort the array, and then search for the words using, say, [Array#bsearch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch). Perhaps that's what the person who suggested using a binary search tree had in mind. Consider also performing the task with a shell script, using Unix tools like grep, awk, grep, and so on. See [this SO question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113693/how-to-count-specific-strings-in-file).